# Jquery simple AJAX get not working in IE(8)

Tags: jquery, get

I'm having the simplest AJAX get call possible (working in FF), yet not working in IE(8), I don't know why nor can find a way to debug this:

```
var jqxhr3 = $.get(
"http://server-url:3333/path_to_file?PROJECT_ID=2&BROWSER_ID=1"
)
```

This call is done from a server that is on the same network, but not on the "server-url" machine, is that a cross-domain issue?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's a cross-domain issue.  Look into JSONP.

[Here's a good tutorial](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/wa-aj-jsonp1/) on how JSONP works.

Comment: When trying to use `var jqxhr3 = jQuery.getJSON(
    "http://server-url:3333/path_to_file?PROJECT_ID=2&BROWSER_ID=1", function (json) {
        alert("JSON Data");
    });
`